# Animate repeat and iOS app lifecycle

Tags: ios, animation, lifecycle, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate a `UIImageView` and have it resume/start animation after the app is minimized (Home button, entering another app, etc) and reentered. I do the following in my `viewDidLoad` method to create the animation, the path I want, and a rotation:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, startX, startY);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, startX, startY, curvePoint1X, curvePoint1Y, endX, endY);
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = duration;
animation.path = path;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"theAnimation"];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0 options:0
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
                         [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
                         imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

It works great, but when I hit the Home button and go back to my app, the animation is not playing and my views are in the origin position. How can I set this animation to start again when the app is reentered? I don't mind if the animation has to start from the beginning. I have an `NSTimer` running in my app as well and I know it resumes, I was thinking to run a check there to resume animation but I'm not sure that's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I figured out a solution to my problem. I have an 'NSTimer' running and check periodically if my views are moving by looking at the presentation layer frame and if the animation isn't moving, I start the animation again. Checking the presentation layer frame was the tricky part and I did this:

```
-(BOOL) isViewNotMoving:(UIImageView *) imageView {
  // Grab values from view presentation layer and compare to test movement
  CGRect viewLocation = [[[imageView layer] presentationLayer] frame];
  double currentX = viewLocation.origin.x;
  double currentY = viewLocation.origin.y;
  BOOL testResult = false;
  if ((currentX - previousX == 0) && (currentY - previousY == 0)) {
      testResult = true;
  } else {
      testResult = false;
  }
  previousX = currentX;
  previousY = currentY;

  return testResult;
}
```

where `previousX` and `previousY` are declared before. Hope some else finds this useful.